# Server Time - driving me nuts :-)

Tags: php, datetime

Okay so I have a server in Denver with a user in New Zealand. I know everything about the user (timezone etc) and through the program they request something to happen in advance - let's say at 11:30am on August 5th 2013. I have a CRON job that runs every 15 minutes and asks the database if any requests are pending for the next 15 minute period, but how do I convert their stored time to the servers equivalent.

1. I set the default timezone for calculations: `date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver')`
2. I take the time now on the server and turn it into epoch: `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`
3. I add the 15 minutes to create a range: `$forward15 = strtotime('now +15 minutes')`
4. I get the user chosen date from the database (and their timezone): `2013-08-05 11:30:00`

Now what? If I convert that into epoch, it'll just be the servers version of that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW SOLUTION SEE BELOW!**

If you know the timezone you can simply "add" it to your time.

For example:

server time: 01/01/01 00:00
the time the user wants: 01/01/01 01:00
the timezone of the user: GMT - 5

Just get the time (01/01/01 01:00) and add +5 => 01/01/01 06:00

So: your script needs to be executed at 01/01/01 06:00

(convert to timestamp where needed)

Added a little php to demonstrate

```
<?php

$servertime = time(); //timestamp of 01/01/01 00:00
$usertime = "01/01/01 06:00";//database
$userUTC = "-5";//database
strreplace($userUTC, "-", "+";
$replacetext = $userUTC . " days";
$usertime = strtotime($replacetext, $usertime);//now usertime is in your local timezone

$crontime = date("d/m/Y H:i");//the time you want the script to be executed

?>
```

I'm just assuming that the timezone is saved as "-5" for example and not Europe/Amsterdam Just tell me if i'm wrong.

edit 14:37

This could be a even better solution i think!

```
<?php
$usertime = "01/01/01 06:00";
$userUTC = "-5";
$userdate = $usertime . " " . $userUTC;
$usertimestamp = strtotime($userdate);//now you have the timestamp with correct timezone
$crontime = date("d/m/Y H:i", $usertimestamp);//formatted to the right date
echo $crontime;
?>
```

Edit: 25-07-2013 14:26

New solution to suit your database:

```
<?php
$usertime = "01/01/01 06:00";
$userUTC = "Pacific/Auckland";//get from database
$userdate = $usertime . " " . $userUTC;
$usertimestamp = strtotime($userdate);//now you have the timestamp with correct timezone
$crontime = date("d/m/Y H:i", $usertimestamp);//formatted to the right date
echo $crontime;
?>
```

Comment: Wouldnt I need to convert the users future time into a timestamp first? e.g. $futuredate = new DateTime('2013-08-05 11:30', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Auckland')); $newdate = $futuredate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); $timestamp = strtotime($newdate);

Comment: Yes: i was just giving an idea how to proceed. You can either convert it to a timestamp and add the equivalent of 5 hours or ust the gmdate() function where you can add a offset like explained in the anwser of liyakat

Comment: Newbie question - why 5 hours specifically? Wouldn't the time difference be + or - 5 hours for daylight savings PLUS an additional location specific difference? Sorry to be so inept at time calculations.

Comment: Well this could be an issue, however it would only occur on the day when the DST goes in effect.

When it is +5 (+1 DST) the server itself will also be +0 (+1 DST)

Comment: Added some code to demonstrate what i mean, i'm sure there is a better way but this is just a quick way to do it!

Comment: Added a new solution please confirm it that would work for you!

Comment: Thank you sooo much Matthjus for your time bud. I am storing the timezone as 'Pacific/Auckland' BTW. So from what I see above all you're doing is taking the future user date and adding 5 to it (if their timezone requires it). Is it really that simple? I suppose it must be since in theory a future date for them is just UTC at that point in time plus their difference from it. And a time stamp is a timestamp so from the servers point of view its just a future point for it too (after adding or subtracting it's difference from it). Thank you - that makes things much clearer.

Comment: Fortunately even when using a timezone in the format of "EU/Amsterdam" it still works like a charm! Please see the example code I added to the end of my answer. 
Please upvote so others can also benefit from this solution

If you have any more questions feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

the server is in which GMT time zone here is extremely easy way to get time and date for any time zone. This is done with time() and gmdate() function. gmdate() function normally give us GMT time but by doing a trick with time() function we can get GMT+N or GMT-N means we can get time for any GMT time zone.

For example you have to get time for GMT+5 we will do it like following

```
<?php 
  $offset=5*60*60; //converting 5 hours to seconds.
  $dateFormat="d-m-Y H:i";
  $timeNdate=gmdate($dateFormat, time()+$offset);
?>
```

Now if you have to get the time which is GMT-5 now we will just subtract the offset from the time() instead of adding into time like in following example we are getting time for GMT-4

```
<?php 
  $offset=4*60*60; //converting 5 hours to seconds.
  $dateFormat="d-m-Y H:i";
  $timeNdate=gmdate($dateFormat, time()-$offset);
?>
```